# How to create a multiGeometry in EarthEngine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/geometries), earthengine supports `GeometryCollection` as `MultiGeometry`.
For testing purposes I would like to create one manually, but I fail to find the corresponding class in the Geometry objects:

```py
point0 = ee.Geometry.Point([0,0])
point1 = ee.Geometry.Point([0,1])
poly0 = point0.buffer(1)
poly2 = point1.buffer(1).bounds()
line = ee.Geometry.LineString([point1, point0])
multiPoly = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon([poly0, poly2])
geometryCol = ee.Geometry.MultiGeometry([poly0, poly2, line, point0]) # this doesn't work
```

Does anyone have already created one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

earthengine MultiGeometry constructor is more complex than classi geometries so it's stored in the Algorithms class:

```py
geometryCol = ee.Algorithms.GeometryConstructors.MultiGeometry(
    geometries = [poly0, poly2, line, point0], 
    geodesic=True, 
    maxError=1
)
```